# What does "This post is super-awesome" when creating a new post mean?

Tags: wordpress.com

I see the checkbox "This post is super-awesome" but not sure what it means. Please explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A search for

> wordpress "this post is super awesome"

with the quotes revealed some blogs about the "Surprise Me" option that has been added to Wordpress. Checking "Surprise Me" enables this checkbox on posts.

A lot of the posts mention that if you check this option something happens after you hit "Publish" but are coy about what that "something" is.

The comments on [this thread](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/can-suprise-me-cue-a-video?replies=6) on the WordPress.com forums indicates you get to see a video.

Comment: You indeed get a video. Its similar to the Funny or Die voting button.